# Need help finding memoryleak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have been sitting for hours now, and it's driving me nuts. Im new too c++ so if something else besides the memoryleaks is wrong I would love to know! :D

The thing is that if I make a new teacher/assistant/TA  and print it I get:

```
{212} normal block at 0x005694B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  V     > BC 91 56 00 00 00 00 00 
{210} normal block at 0x005691B8, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <      V Oliver  > BC A4 16 00 B0 94 56 00 4F 6C 69 76 65 72 00 CD 
{209} normal block at 0x00568F30, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  V     > 90 8E 56 00 00 00 00 00 
{208} normal block at 0x00569468, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <d V     > 64 8E 56 00 00 00 00 00 
{204} normal block at 0x00568E60, 76 bytes long.
 Data: <    h V elev    > D4 A6 16 00 68 94 56 00 65 6C 65 76 00 CD CD CD
```

If I keep repeting it just stacks up, would appreciate all the help I can get! :D

```
    int main(){



    int choise, count=0;
    bool ta = false , teacher = false, assistant = false;
    choise = meny();

    Employee **work = NULL;
    Employee **swapper = NULL;
    Employment *tmp = NULL;

    string name, types, subject, temp, type;
    int birthyear, salary, workhours, points;
    bool boss = false, ansvarig, key=false, cert;

    while (choise != NULL){
        if (choise > 0){

            if (choise == 1){
                fflush(stdin);
                cout << endl << "Namn: ";
                getline(cin, name);
                cout << endl << "Fodelsear: ";
                cin >> birthyear;
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nTjänst: ";
                getline(cin, type);
                cout << "\nLon: ";
                cin >> salary;
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nChef: ";
                cin >> temp;
                cin.ignore();
                if (temp == "Ja" || temp == "ja"){
                    boss = true;
                }
                else
                    boss = false;
                cout << "\nTjanstgoringstid: ";
                cin >> workhours;
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nHuvudämne: ";
                cin >> subject;
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nProgramansvarig: ";
                cin >> temp;
                cout << "\n\n\n";
                cin.ignore();
                if (temp == "Ja" || temp == "ja")
                    ansvarig = true;
                else
                    ansvarig = false;



                count++;
                teacher = true;

            }
            else if (choise == 2){
                fflush(stdin);
                cout << endl << "Namn: ";
                getline(cin, name);

                cout << endl << "Fodelsear: ";
                cin >> birthyear;
                fflush(stdin);

                cout << "\nTjänst: ";
                getline(cin, type);

                cout << "\nLon: ";
                cin >> salary;
                fflush(stdin);

                cout << "\nHuvudämne: ";
                cin >> subject;
                fflush(stdin);

                cout << "Avklarade poang: ";
                cin >> points;
                fflush(stdin);
                count++;

                assistant = true;
            }
            else if (choise == 3){

                fflush(stdin);

                cout << endl << "Namn: ";
                getline(cin, name);

                cout << endl << "Fodelsear: ";
                cin >> birthyear;
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "\nTjänst: ";
                getline(cin, type);


                cout << "\nLon: ";
                cin >> salary;
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "\nTjanstgoringstid: ";
                cin >> workhours;
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "\nAttestratt: ";
                cin >> temp;
                cin.ignore();
                if (temp == "Ja" || temp == "ja"){
                    cert = true;
                }
                else
                    cert = false;

                cout << "\nHar huvudnyckel: ";
                cin >> temp;
                cin.ignore();
                if (temp == "Ja" || temp == "ja"){
                    cert = true;
                }
                else
                    cert = false;


                cout << "\n\n\n";




                count++;
                ta = true;
            }

            else if (choise == 4){
                for (int x = 0; x < (count); x++){
                    cout << work[x]->toString();
                }
            }
            if (choise != 0 && choise!=4){
                swapper = new Employee*[count];

                if (teacher == true){
                    tmp = new Teacher(type, boss, salary, workhours, subject, ansvarig);

                    swapper[count - 1] = new Employee(name, birthyear, tmp);

                    teacher = false;

                    //delete tmp;
                }
                else if (ta == true){
                    tmp = new TA(type, boss, salary, workhours, cert, key);

                    swapper[count - 1] = new Employee(name, birthyear, tmp);

                    assistant = false;

                //  delete tmp;
                }
                else if (assistant == true){
                    tmp = new Assistant(type, salary, subject, points);


                    swapper[count - 1] = new Employee(name, birthyear, tmp);

                //  delete tmp;


                }



                    for (int x = 0; x < count - 1; x++){
                    swapper[x] = work[x];
                    }



                delete[] work;



                work = swapper;



            }

                choise = meny();




        }
    }

    /*for (int x = 0; x < count; x++){
        delete work[x];
        }*/

    delete [] work;



    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you're having difficulty. You perform memory management manually, your code is nigh-on unreadable and there are no comments!

Comment: Please submit a new question asking for help "refactoring" your code, which includes a description of the assignment in addition to your existing code.  You will get much better help that way.

Answer (score 2):

You never `delete` your arrays. You should use vectors anyway.

Comment: @Prolle: `swapper = new Employee*[count];`

Comment: If I try to delete swaper next to my delete[] work; I get debug assertion failed. _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID/(pHead->nBlockUse)

where should I delete my swapper? :D

Answer (score 0):

The thing is basically that for every `new` you make, you need to have a `delete` when the object is no longer needed. 
Doing this deallocate the memory. If you don't, you keep pilling up amounts of allocated memories forever and ever.

Comment: But I strongly suggest you change the way of allocating memory. A simple way would be to implement constructors and destructors which would be a lot clearer to follow. Using new and delete in your main is NEVER the better way to do it.

Comment: or a very VERY better way to do would be to simply use vectors. for example vector<assistant>, vector<employee> etc.

Comment: HMm will try vector out! :D

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks occur whenever you dynamically allocate memory and do not release it. This means that for every `new` that appears in your program, a corresponding `delete` must exist or else you're leaking memory.

There are a lot of `delete`s that have been commented out in your code (e.g., for `tmp`). So, right off the bat, we know for sure those allocations are leaking.

Likewise the memory you're allocating for `swapper` isn't getting deallocated (at least the first time through the loop). Additionally, even though you invoke `delete [] work`, you aren't `delete`ing the individual elements in the array, which are also dynamically allocated.

And since all these allocations occur within a loop, it's no wonder that you have so many leaks!